# $F = \{f \in C^{1}([a,b]): f(a) = 0\}$ not complete

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $F = \{f \in C^{1}([a,b]): f(a) = 0\}$ with 
$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{a}^{b} f'(x) \overline{g'(x)} dx$

Determine if $F$ with $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ is a Hilbert Space.

I believe the answer to be no. Without the $f(a) = 0$ condition, I would use something like

$f_{n}(x) = \sqrt{x + \frac{1}{n}}$ to show the space isn't complete, but this sequence wouldn't be in $F$.

Once you throw in the $f(a) = 0$ condition, I'm not sure of an appropriate Cauchy sequence. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside: The condition $f(a)=0$ is actually what tells you that $\langle f,f \rangle =0$.

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $f_n \in F$ be such that, for $x>a+\frac{1}{n}$, $f_n(x)=1$ (this is possible by elementary calculus, glue a thin upside-down parabola to a constant). Then $f_n'\to 0$ pointwise, so, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem,
$$
\langle f_n,f_m\rangle =\int_a^b (f_n'-f_m')^2dx\to 0
$$
as $n,m\to \infty$. But the limiting function is not continuous.

Comment: Yes, in fact the same functions extended to vanish outside of $[a,b]$ (again, you need to smoothen them, but this is easy), should do the trick.

Comment: This is something I could do explicitly as well, right? Like, make my parabola be $1- n^2(x-a - \frac{1}{n})^2$ for $a \le x \le a + \frac{1}{n}$. I ask because I'd prefer not to use Dominated Convergence Theorem since I have not covered it in my class.

Comment: Yeah, if you describe your functions explicitly, you can just compute the integral and then take the limit. My appeal to the Dominated Convergence Theorem was mostly out of laziness.